# BIND: Whitelist IPs using nsupdate

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I know that we can add any kind of DNS records in BIND DNS server using nsupdate. Can we whitelist or blacklist any ip in realtime using nsupdate. We whitelist only certain IPs to prevent our DNS server from being used as open resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Being an open resolver isn't a bad thing automatically, though nobody particularly cares so long as your server is rate limited to prevent abuse in a DNS Amplification attack. In any case, if you're restricting this, you use the `allow-recursion {}` directive in the `options` clause of the configuration file. Within that block, just add your internal IPs, don't forget the loopback IP for the server running BIND. The default setting is to allow recursion from everyone.

To restrict what IPs can send updates via `nsupdate` you can use the `allow-update` directive. By default the server allows updates from any IP, and each zone allows updates from none. You can change this within the global `options` clause or within each zone individually. This option can also take ACLs, and Keys to allow/deny updates (it's generally a good idea to allow updates by Key only).

Comment: I want to whitelist some new elastic IP in AWS in real time using nsupdate. Can we do that ? If yes, can you please give some example.

Comment: No, you can't change the running configuration without a reload. See the comment about keys.

Comment: But we can add and delete any kind of DNS records using nsupdate without reload. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nsupdate

Comment: Yes, `nsupdate` can add or delete any record in a dynamic zone.

Comment: Can I whitelist/blacklist an IP also dynamically using nsupdate ? This is my question

Comment: No, the allowed IPs are part of the running configuration, not DNS records.

Comment: **Being an open-resolver is automatically a bad thing.**  Bad actors can use it to generate traffic to a victim regardless of rate limiting.  Rate limiting is good for the case where you are responding to a (possibly spoofed) source query in one of your authoritative zones that is being asked repeatedly at a high rate.

Comment: If there were no open resolvers, there would be no Internet as we know it. Also, DNS runs on TCP just fine if the client is configured to do so. And blocking DNS will definitely not stop an attacker, you can bounce a TCP-SYN reflection off any server that responds, like every web server in the world; or any other number of attacks.. DNS just happened to be the flavor of the month, now they're using NTP, next it will be something else...

Answer (score 1):

`nsupdate` only gives you the ability to modify records in zones on your server, it does not allow you to change the configuration and updating ACLs is a config change. (See [RFC 2136](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2136.txt))